# How to mock a constructor used in React componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test React component with mapbox-gl and using Jest and react-testing-library.
Inside Component, I'm using mapbox constructor and assigning an instance to `this.map`
In componentWillUnmount calling `this.map.remove()` and it leads to error in test.

Code of the component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import "./Map.css";

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.map = null;
    this.mapContainer = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer.current,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      center: [37.61513, 55.7513461], 
      zoom: 11,
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.map.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        data-testid="map"
        className="map-container"
        ref={this.mapContainer}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Trying to test it e.g:

```
import Map from "../../page/Map/Map";
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

jest.mock('mapbox-gl', () => ({
    Map: jest.fn(() => ({
        remove: jest.fn()
    })),
}));

describe('Map.js', () => {    
    it('should call mapbox-gl', function () {
        const { getByTestId } = render( <Map />);
        expect(mapboxgl.Map).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            container: getByTestId('map'),
            style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
            center: [37.61513, 55.7513461],
            zoom: 11,
        });
    });
})
```

And got this error:

Map.js › should call mapbox-gl

```
TypeError: this.map.remove is not a function

  22 |
  23 |   componentWillUnmount() {
> 24 |     this.map.remove();
     |              ^
  25 |   }
  26 |
  27 |   render() {
```

Comment: try `jest.mock('mapbox-gl')` and then use `import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";`

Answer (score 1):

As per [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestfnimplementation) ,

> `jest.fn()` Returns a new, unused mock function. Optionally takes a mock implementation.

[image]

`jest.fn()` rerurns is spy function which doesn't have a constructor, so you won't be able to create object for (mapbox-gl.Map) with `new`, thus there's no properties called `remove` or etc..

```
jest.mock('mapbox-gl', () => ({
    Map: jest.fn(() => ({ -> is mocked function and it doesn't have a constructor 
        remove: jest.fn()
    })),
}));
```

To mock modules, you need to use `jest.mock`, something like below.

`jest.mock('mapbox-gl')` will automatically mocks the properties of `mapbox-gl` and returns a wrapped spies object.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
jest.mock('mapbox-gl')
```

insted of

```
jest.mock('mapbox-gl', () => ({
    Map: jest.fn(() => ({
        remove: jest.fn()
    })),
}));
```

Helps, but don't have a clue why the first one doesn't work.